# Изменение текста в теге

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть вот такая конструкция `div`

```
<div id="clickme" style="width: 240px; border:1px solid #CCC; height:199px;  z-index:999; background:red;" ><a href="#"  id="animate" >show</a></div>
```

при нажатии на `show` выполняется скрипт

```
$("#animate").click(function() {
    $("#clickme")
        .animate({"height": "600px"}, 1100)
        .animate({"width": "650px"}, 1100);
});
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после выполнения скрипта надпись в теге `<a>` менялась с `show` на `hide`. И при нажатии на `hide` див приобретал начальное значение. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @raptor96, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). Если Вы нашли решение сами, поделитесь с сообществом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант покороче через **toggle** - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPFeW/2/)

```
$("#animate").toggle(function() {

 $("#clickme")
        .animate({"height": "600px"}, 1100)
        .animate({"width": "650px"}, 1100);

  $(this).text('hide');

},function() {

  $("#clickme")
        .animate({"height": "200px"}, 1100)
        .animate({"width": "250px"}, 1100);

  $(this).text('show');

});
```

Comment: Я бы только добавил, что если автору надо смену текста именно "после выполнения скрипта", то это [делаем таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/sPFeW/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант [клик](http://jsfiddle.net/sPFeW/):

```js
$("#animate").click(function() {

  if ($(this).attr('data-sh') == 'n') {

    $("#clickme")
      .animate({
        "height": "600px"
      }, 1100)
      .animate({
        "width": "650px"
      }, 1100);

    $(this).attr('data-sh', 'y').text('hide');
  } else {
    $("#clickme")
      .animate({
        "height": "200px"
      }, 1100)
      .animate({
        "width": "250px"
      }, 1100);

    $(this).attr('data-sh', 'n').text('show');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickme" style="width: 240px; border:1px solid #CCC; height:199px;  z-index:999; background:red;">
  <a href="#" id="animate" data-sh="n">show</a>
</div>
```